# Calling VB6 Active X DLL from C# .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a VB6 project that has 10 forms in it. I need to call this VB6 form from my .Net 2.0 C# code.

Steps followed by me:

1. Created ActiveX DLL of my VB6 Project.
2. Register the DLL in the system.
3. Created the object of the DLL Class and tried calling the function of from to open from .NET

I used below code to call the VB6 form:

```
 Type obj = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(strObjectType);
   object ins = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(strObjectType));
   obj.InvokeMember(strInvoke, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ins, null);
```

Function in VB6 is called and that internally calling to the Form1.Show, it is giving me error as:

> Non-modal forms cannot be displayed in this host application from an ActiveX DLL, ActiveX Control, or Property Page

Require help to solve this issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem to me there's anything to solve - the error message is indicating that you're trying to load the form and display it, but it cannot be displayed because it's non-modal. If the VB6 DLL code creates a non-modal dialog, you'll have to change *that* code to get around the problem (eg make it a modal dialog).

Comment: Thanks David, let me give a try to change the modal. will keep you posted the progress